# Will A Logarithmic Potentiometer Linearise A Capacitor Charge Curve?

Tags: analog, capacitance

I want to use a rising voltage on a capacitor to set more than one trigger points for events via comparators; that is when the voltage reaches a certain level, the comparator goes high. For ease I want to set the trigger points with simple potential dividers for now. The problem is that a capacitor charge curve isn't linear. So I'm trying to figure out if the use of a log pot will "cancel" that out, since my maths frankly isn't up to analysing the two curves against one another. The intention is to get a roughly linear scale on the pot rather than having all the values bunched up at one end of the pot's rotation.

If this does work, will it get messed up by having fixed resistors in series with the pot to limit the voltage range?

Comment: Please attach a schematic showing what you're trying to do and how you plan to connect the potentiometers.

Comment: I haven't got a schematic to attach I'm afraid. This is a general question really about whether the two curves (capacitor charge and log scale) are the same shape.

Comment: It's just that it takes 2 seconds to see what you're trying to do from a schematic, while trying to decode someone's written idea of a hypothetical circuit is slow, error-prone, and impossible to reference in an answer. One thing to keep in mind is that a lot of "log" pots aren't very close to being "log", more like two linear segments. It may be easier to charge the cap from a simple current source which can be made from two transistors and two resistors, which gives a linear voltage ramp.

Comment: That was my initial idea, but I couldn't find an appropriate circuit for that on the web, and I'm getting back into electronics after a number of years neglecting it and am rather rusty, hence I wondered if this might be a workable kludge. It doesn't have to be precise, but TBH I'd much prefer a linear ramp, but I don't know how to do that. Is there a fairly simple (and cheap!) circuit for acheiving a linear ramp voltage? That would be ideal.

Comment: @IanBland In response to "a linear ramp voltage", you would typically do that by integrating a constant, which is a relatively simple circuit.

Comment: @IanBland I know, pretty embarassing. Googling for "current source" only gives listings for current _sinks_ (all labled current source). The easiest I found was this link: http://homepages.which.net/~paul.hills/Circuits/RxDecoder/RxDecoder.html which may have more info.

Comment: A good rule of thumb for delay circuits is use a divider where the bottom is 2x the top. For example, 1k on top and 2k on the bottom. Then the delay will be very close to R * C, where R and C make up the low pass filter on the other side of the comparator. You may be able to daisy chain (cascade) several comparators to get sequenced triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a circuit like this to charge your capacitor:

[image]

With the circuit values shown this will produce a linear ramp of capacitor voltage from 0V up to 4.4V over a time span of 7 msec.

[image]

The pulse source in the schematic provides the reset for the ramp voltage holding it initially at GND. You can repeat the ramp by driving the NPN base high for a short pulse to discharge the capacitor to GND. The ramp will then begin again when the NPN base goes low and the NPN shuts off.

Timing of the ramp can be adjusted by changing the value of R1 and/or C1.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this circuit and with the other responses I think I can do what I want now without the log pot thing :)